# How can I mimic CTRL+A, CTRL+C in WebBrowser Control through COM or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, com, browser, webbrowser-control

How can I mimic <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in WebBrowser Control automatically via COM?

Alternatively, is there a way of simulating this behaviour using JavaScript?

I looked all over and it seems that the only way to put data into the clipboard is to use the `setData()` method of the `clipboardData` object, but I end up with HTML being interpreted as text. What I need is to put an entire webpage into the clipboard so it can be pasted into MS Word.

Comment: You might want to review Raymond Chen's recent blog entry on this topic: [What happens when applications try to copy text by sending Ctrl+C](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/23/10178000.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, John! On this site, if you find the answer yourself, it's considered good form to add and accept an answer instead of editing your question. That way, other users browsing the list of questions can see that there's an answer. I'll fix this one for you (you'll have to accept it yourself by clicking the hollow checkmark icon at the left of the answer, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer was discovered by the OP and posted as an update to the question. Just moving it here for semantics.*

Here's the solution in JavaScript (can be used through COM as well):

```
window.document.execCommand('SelectAll',true);
window.document.execCommand('Copy',true);
window.document.execCommand('UnSelect',true);
```

Comment: Thanks! The system told me that I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, so I had to add to the answer, thanks for editing, good sport!

Comment: Interesting, I forgot or didn't know there was a reputation threshold for self-answering. In any case, you're welcome, and good (bug) hunting!